# How to create a dynamic text box with time picker

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I am working in a an application where i have  to generate multiple textboxes and also i need to add timepicker into them .Now in my application i am able to create the mutiple textboxes dynamically.But i am not able to put timepicker on that.Here is my code

```
$(function () {
$("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
    var div = $("<div />");
    div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
    $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
});
$("#btnGet").bind("click", function () {
    var valuesarr = new Array();   
    var phonearr = new Array();  
    var phonearr1 = new Array(); 
    $("input[name=DynamicTextBox]").each(function () {
        valuesarr.push($(this).val());
        $('#DynamicTextBox').val(valuesarr);
    });
    $("input[name=phoneNum]").each(function () {
        phonearr.push($(this).val());
        $('#phoneNum').val(phonearr);
    });

    $("input[name=phoneNum1]").each(function () {
        phonearr1.push($(this).val());
        $('#phoneNum1').val(phonearr1);
    });

    alert(valuesarr); alert(phonearr);alert(phonearr1);
});

$("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
});

});


function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
   return '<input name = "DynamicTextBox" type="text" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;<input id="myPicker" class="time" type="text" />&nbsp;<input name = "phoneNum1" type="text" /><input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove" />';
}
```

Here is the fiddle i want to add two timepickers in the 2nd and 3 rd box

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/info2jeet/hfmjajce/)
Somebody pLease help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE THIS:
`$("#myPicker").timepicker();` //add this on Add click.if you are willing to create multiple time picker better use class.you can use : `$(".time").timepicker();` also where time is the class attached to the input field.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
        var div = $("<div />");
        div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
       // $("#myPicker").timepicker();//add this
        $(".time").timepicker();
    });
    $("#btnGet").bind("click", function () {
        var valuesarr = new Array();   
        var phonearr = new Array();  
        var phonearr1 = new Array(); 
        $("input[name=DynamicTextBox]").each(function () {
            valuesarr.push($(this).val());
            $('#DynamicTextBox').val(valuesarr);
        });
        $("input[name=phoneNum]").each(function () {
            phonearr.push($(this).val());
            $('#phoneNum').val(phonearr);
        });
        
        $("input[name=phoneNum1]").each(function () {
            phonearr1.push($(this).val());
            $('#phoneNum1').val(phonearr1);
        });
       
        alert(valuesarr); alert(phonearr);alert(phonearr1);
    });
    
    $("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
        $(this).closest("div").remove();
    });
    
});

function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
       return '<input name = "DynamicTextBox" type="text" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;<input id="myPicker" class="time" type="text" />&nbsp;<input name = "phoneNum1" id="phoneNum1" class="time"  type="text" /><input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove" />';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.css">
<div id="TextBoxContainer">
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you  very much one question i want  both textboxes with timepicker what should i modify ?

Comment: i have updated the answer see now both will have timepicker.